# Get last 5 tweets

Tags: node.js, twitter

How can I get the last 5 tweets?
Currently I use this: https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/

I use the example code:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});

var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs'};
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);
  }
});
```

I only changed the 'nodejs' part to different name and filled the twitter keys.
I get a big json in console.
How can I do that the last 5 tweets I will get and every 30 minutes it will check if there is a new tweet or not? If there is new tweet then it would show in console the new tweet only and it would not the same tweets which the program retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation for the user timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) you'll see that you can use the `count` parameter.

> Specifies the number of Tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum of 200 per distinct request.

In your code, you'll need:

```
var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs', count: 5};
```

That will get you the most recent 5 tweets from that account.